# Infinity Initializing JS/TS language features when open file ".jsw"

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, velo

[image]

When setup local coding for Wix studio, i use vscode to coding, Wix use backend file contains javascript code with ".jsw" ext.

When i open jsw file and set the file type associate with javascript, the Infinity Initializing JS/TS language features start loading and never stop
The sequences is i can't use intellsense in normal ".js" file.

Any one can help me?

Comment: does the content of the file matter? what if the file is empty, or as minimal as possible? ([mre]) also, check the Output Panel's channel for TypeScript and see if there are any related-looking messages there.